# Amplify.Storage.** does not work for me on Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS Amplify to make an Android app. I followed the official tutorial to add Authentication, API, and Storage. https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-android-app-amplify/module-one/ . But when I run Amplify.Storage.** it doesn't respond at all. There is no error message so I cannot track the issue. Does anyone have suggestions as to what might be wrong?

This is my uploadFile() function:

```
fun storeAudio(filePath: String, key: String) {

        val file = File(filePath)
        val options = StorageUploadFileOptions.builder()
            .accessLevel(StorageAccessLevel.PROTECTED)
            .build()

        scope.launch {
            Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
                key,
                file,
                options,
                { progress -> Log.i(TAG, "Fraction completed: ${progress.fractionCompleted}") },
                { result -> Log.i(TAG, "Successfully uploaded: " + result.key) },
                { error -> Log.e(TAG, "Upload failed", error) }
            )
        }
}
```

Amplify is configured properly. And my amplifyconfiguration.json file looks correct, but let me know if you need to take a look at it.